# How apt-get handle my manual installed software?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Supporse the emacs version in apt repository is 24.3, I `configure && make install` my own emacs 24.4. After a long time, the software in apt repository updated to 24.5. What would apt do when I run `apt-get update && atp-get safeupgrade`?

What's the general way to let apt handle my manual installed software?

Comment: Off-topic, try http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: It would probably overwrite your manually installed version. Better ask this at Unix.SE, as this is off-topic here.

Comment: There's tag for apt and ubuntu, so I post the question here. Ok, I'll post it on unix.stackexchange Thank you.

Comment: Just for your info, the apt and ubuntu tags are here only for questions related to programming (some issue that only happens on Ubuntu or related to Ubuntu software like their desktop environment or whatever).

Comment: @AndréDaniel Got it. Thank you! Should I delete this question?

Comment: I guess there's nothing else to do, so yes. For next time though, remember that deleted questions count towards the question ban so if you happen to do it enough times you may run into it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `configure && make install` is not installing a software package, so apt doesn't notice or care. If you see that there is an update, remove your manually built code and run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. Apt CAN NOT manage your manually built software unless you install it as a package. Use this to create your own packages: https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian.